# Type error at ... 'myModel' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, web, typeerror

```
67  <h2>Latest Posts</h2>
68  
69  <ul>
70      {% for post in posts %}
71              <li><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{post.title}}</a></li>
72      {% endfor %}
73  </ul>
```

**this is my base template and when i click a post,getting an error at line 70:**

```
TypeError at /blog/posts/indiana-was-dogs-name/
'Blog' object is not iterable
```

**my blog models:**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/blog/posts/%s/" % self.slug
```

**my index view:**

def index(request):

```
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
                                         'categories': Category.objects.all(),
                                         'posts': Blog.objects.filter(posted__lte=datetime.now()).order_by('-posted', 'title')
                                        })
    return render_to_response('index.html',variables)
```

**there are a few posts about error like this but not including my problem**

Comment: What are posts? Are you sure they are iterable? The error is not in the template...its the view code.

Comment: updated my answer, maybe it'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says, the `blogs` variable you pass to your template is not iterable.
You can only iterate through lists and other iterables, and in your case, `blogs` is a `Blog` instance, where it should be a `QuerySet`. You may write, for example

```
blogs = Blog.objects.all()
return render_to_response(..., {'blogs':blogs,...} ...}
```

**Edit**

I would feel more safe if you used the exact syntax given in the Django docs. Maybe the difference of syntax is the culprit, I really don't see yet otherwise.

```
render_to_response(template_name[, dictionary][, context_instance][, mimetype])
```

with dictionary set to `{'categories': Category.objects.all(), 'posts': Blog.objects.filter(posted__lte=datetime.now()).order_by('-posted', 'title')}` and `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`

Answer (score 1):

```
 return render_to_response('index.html',{'categories':Category.objects.all(), 'posts':Blog.objects.filter(....)},
context_instance=template.RequestContext(request))
```